# Superset Dashboard Embedded on an External Application

Tags: angular, apache-superset

I've created one dashboard in my superset application and I want to embed this dashboard on an angular application and grant access to specific persons to view and edit my dashboard. For this I've added a guest user and able to obtain access and refresh token while login into the application. For security reasons I'm able to see csrf token also on my console. But while creating guest token for the guest I added csrf and access tokens as headers into it. But not able to generate guest token and showing these errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9mzO.png)

Anyone please help me out to tackle this issue. Or is there any alternative way for doing the same

Comment: you are using helm? can you show more details about your custom flags (like 'PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE', 'ENABLE_CORS'...)